# ClassBridge called by MassIndexer and access to spring service

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-search

I wonder whether it is possible to use any spring services from within hibernate search ClassBridge.

*Abstract:*

My entity does not have all information i'd like to put into indexed document. I can not get it by [@IndexedEmbeded](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-mapping-associated) too. This data comes from external data source, and I have service to provide this. This is only needed when reindexing. When indexing single object save service provide this information in transient entity field.
For reindex I use MassIndexer.

My application is working in Spring MVC environment. I use annotation driven configuration. So to access my service I need only use @Autowired annotation and service is ready to be used.

*Solution?*

When using Hibernate Search life is not so easy (or I have no idea how it could be).

To get additional information I decided to use [ClassBridge](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e4327). I also implement simple [MassIndexer](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-batchindex-massindexer) procedure called from within my spring service.

In my ClassBridge spring does not autowire service. When I try do quick workaround and use static field in ClassBridge and pass service reference from MassIndexer caller the other problem occurred. Service reports exception "no session" (sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() throws exception)... I have no idea where to go further.

What is recommended way to access Spring service from within ClassBridge code?

How can I get active hibernate Session (or SessionFactory) from within ClassBridge?

Thanx for you time & hope your help.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is through compile time weaving and @Configurable

Comment: Can you explain it more? I can not imagine final solution :(

Answer (score 0):

A comment on this page (http://guylabs.ch/2014/02/22/autowiring-pring-beans-in-hibernate-jpa-entity-listeners/)  provides a much simpler way of handling this that might be useful.  You can have Spring autowire an object for you, more explicitly by calling:

```
SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
```

Doc: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.html